# Dump a tcp stream (tcpdump/tpick?) and save to file only if RST happen

Tags: tcp, tcpdump, dump, stream

I'm looking for a way to capture a whole tcp stream, but save it into the file only if 
1) error happens (like RST)
2) not sure if possible - analyze the http response, store if HTTP 500 happen is a stream.

The network flow is high, so I'd like to aviod capturing whole traffic.

For the moment the **tcpick** may be the way:

> Example:
>
> log http data in unique files (client and server mixed together):
>
> ```
>      # tcpick -i eth0 "port 80" -wRub
> ```

I could then analyze the saved files, and remove the correct one - but it is an overkill :/